# "Can only recur from tail position, compiling" error while using recur in loop

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojure-repl

I'm very newbie with Clojure, and for practice I am trying to apply a simple algorithm for semi random numbers.

A few days ago, I read about loops in the docs of clojure, and how they work using `recur`, so I tried to write a loop with this lines of code:

```
(def numbers_semi_random
  (fn []      
    (loop[Xn 4 count 0]                    
     (while (and (not (= Xn m)) (< count m))
       (println (mod (+ (* 5.0 Xn) 7.0) m))
       (recur (mod (+ (* 5.0 Xn) 7.0) m) (inc count))    
))))
```

But when I execute the code, this error is displayed

```
CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can only recur from tail position, compiling
```

What's happening? `recur` is not in the tail of the function?

Comment: FYI you can write `(defn numbers_semi_random [] ...)` instead of `(def numbers_semi_random (fn [] ...))`.

Comment: Yes, but throw the same error. That part of code i try to practice when i saw in the docs, in the section of recur. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tail position is the last form that needs to be evaluated before leaving scope. When using `loop`, the `recur` statement must be able to start fresh with new bindings, no further calculations from the previous loop left to be done.

In your code, you have a `while` block in the tail position of the `loop`. The place where you try to call `recur` is not in the loop's tail position (though it is in the tail of its tail).

Perhaps you intended for the `recur` call to be outside the `while`? But the comparison of loop bindings `Xn` and `count` to the global variable `m` in the test for `while` makes me think there is more to be untangled here. How many nested loops do you want here?

Comment: I so sorry, i saw my error, i dont saw all the information in the docs about special forms: http://clojure.org/special_forms, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Agreed on the first paragraph, but the `recur` is not "in the tail of the loop's tail" – if it were, then it would in fact be in tail position w.r.t. the loop. (If X is the last thing to do within Y and Y is the last thing to do within Z, then X is the last thing to do within Z.) The reason why it's not is to do with the shape of `while`'s expansion, I posted an answer to explain that in more detail.

Answer (score 7):

It seems likely that your intention would be accomplished by using `when` in place of `while` (your loop would then keep printing updated values of `Xn` until the condition was met), but to explain the exception:

From the perspective of the compiler, the problem is that while the `while` form is indeed in tail position with respect to your `loop`, the `while` macro's expansion is such that nothing in the `while`'s body is in tail position with respect to the `while` form. (Were the body in tail position w.r.t. the `while` form, it would also be in tail position w.r.t. the enclosing `loop`.)

The reason this is so is that `while` expands to a `loop` expression and supplies its own `recur` after the user-provided body:

```
(while test
  body...)

;; expands to

(loop []
  (when test
    body...
    (recur)))
```

So, if you supply a `recur` as part of the body of `while`, what you get is

```
(loop []
  (when test
    ...
    (recur ...) ; from user code
    (recur)))
```

Here the user-supplied `(recur ...)` is not in tail position with respect to its immediately enclosing `loop`, and this is what the compiler complains about.